# Can I use methods for String class within the String class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, hash, metaprogramming

My new method for a string object in ruby is supposed to return a hash of the count of each character within a string (loaded in from a .txt file) and I am probably trying to go about it the easy way, however I can't seem to make it work without passing the object. I was wondering if there was a way to do this without passing a string. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
class String
  def frequency
    Object.downcase
    Object.gsub("\n", " ")
    h = {}
    h["A:"] = Object.count('a')
    h["B:"] = Object.count('b')
    h["C:"] = Object.count('c')
    h["D:"] = Object.count('d')
    h["E:"] = Object.count('e')
    h["F:"] = Object.count('f')
    h["G:"] = Object.count('g')
    h["H:"] = Object.count('h')
    h["I:"] = Object.count('i')
    h["J:"] = Object.count('j')
    h["K:"] = Object.count('k')
    h["L:"] = Object.count('l')
    h["M:"] = Object.count('m')
    h["N:"] = Object.count('n')
    h["O:"] = Object.count('o')
    h["P:"] = Object.count('p')
    h["Q:"] = Object.count('q')
    h["R:"] = Object.count('r')
    h["S:"] = Object.count('s')
    h["T:"] = Object.count('t')
    h["U:"] = Object.count('u')
    h["V:"] = Object.count('v')
    h["W:"] = Object.count('w')
    h["K:"] = Object.count('x')
    h["Y:"] = Object.count('y')
    h["Z"] = Object.count('z')
return h
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a very long, un-DRY method that iterates your object 26 times, how about using some Ruby:

```
def frequency
  Hash[downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/,'').chars.group_by(&:to_s).map{|char, group| ["#{char.upcase}:", group.size]}]
end
```

You can break this apart onto separate lines if you find it easier to read (and to look up the methods in the API [1]):

```
def frequency
  intermediate_variable = downcase
  intermediate_variable = intermediate_variable.gsub(/[^a-z]/,'') # only keep a-z characters
  intermediate_variable = intermediate_variable.chars.group_by(&:to_s) # split the string into its component characters and then group that array by the characters (run this on an array to see what it does :-)  could also have written it `.group_by{|e|e}`
  intermediate_variable = intermediate_variable.map{|char, group| ["#{char.upcase}:", group.size]} # map the array of grouped characters into an array of character and counts (formatting the 'character' how you would like your hash key configured
  Hash[intermediate_variable] # make a hash of the characters and their counts
end
```

[1] http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html

Comment: Is there anyway to print out the count as the number represented by *'s?

Comment: huh? Are we doing all your homework for you? ;-) `'*' * frequency`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are talking about `self`, which is the ruby keyword that refers to the current object. Note that `self` is implied if you just call the method. So to use your example

```
class String
  def frequency
    count('a')
  end
end
```

would return the number of `a`s in the string

```
"asdfa".frequency #=> 2
```

Just a note, but your current method is very repetitive, and you might want to think about taking advantage of a loop to reduce the amount of code. Also you are not counting capital letters :)

Comment: That's why I tried to use the .downcase so it would make all the capitals lower and then count them

Comment: Fair enough, missed that part!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version I used which is a complete copy of the [Rosetta Letter Frequency](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Ruby_2.0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def letter_frequency(string)
    freq = Hash.new(0)
    string.each_char.lazy.grep(/[[:alpha:]]/).map(&:upcase).each_with_object(freq) do |char, freq_map|
        freq_map[char] += 1
    end
end
```

In ruby you can just open the class and add the method, like:

```
class String
   def my_method
       my_method_code
   end
end
```

Then you just call the method `string.my_method`. However in your case I would rather use a [Ruby module](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm). Here is a code sample, very similar to a class but cleaner imho:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module MyString
    def self.letter_frequency(string)
        freq = Hash.new(0)
        string.each_char.lazy.grep(/[[:alpha:]]/).map(&:upcase).each_with_object(freq) do |char, freq_map|
            freq_map[char] += 1
        end
        return freq
    end
end

p MyString.letter_frequency('absd')
```

Modules are more suited for adding your own classes into projects avoiding name colliding and creating mixins.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a hash like this:

```
class String 
  def frequency
    chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, h|
      h["#{char.upcase}:"] += 1 if char[/[[:alpha:]]/]
    end
  end
end
```